# Issue with array for table based layout: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error

I am developing some code that will involve the storing of three independent test scores in one array. Here is what my code looks like:

```
Results = [
        ["Names  :", []]
        ["Score 1:", []]
        ["Score 2:", []]
        ["Score 3:", []]
        ["Mean   :", []]
        ]
```

It comes up with the error: "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

Comment: Okay? And? Where's your code that actually produces this error?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ This is the code producing the error as the list items are not separated by commas. However, it is not clear if that's the structure the OP really wants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put commas between the top-level lists in your structure. In other words, use

```
Results = [
    ["Names  :", []],
    ["Score 1:", []],
    ["Score 2:", []],
    ["Score 3:", []],
    ["Mean   :", []]
]
```

Your indentation was not ideal in other ways, so I also corrected those aspects. To summarize, a list like `[1 2 3]` is not correct; you need the commas: `[1, 2, 3]`.

With that said, your data structure seems strange. If you will access an inner list by using one of the strings as a key, you should use a dictionary, such as

```
Results = {
    "Names  :": [],
    "Score 1:": [],
    "Score 2:": [],
    "Score 3:": [],
    "Mean   :": []
}
```

or perhaps

```
Results = {
    "Names": [],
    "Score 1": [],
    "Score 2": [],
    "Score 3": [],
    "Mean": []
}
```